# What is the difference between kicking something and kicking out at something?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

1. I kicked out at the dog.
2. I kicked the dog.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I kicked out at the dog.

This means I aimed a kick in the general direction of the dog. My foot may or may not have actually touched it.

> I kicked the dog.

This means I actually kicked the dog - my foot connected with it.

See the Free Dictionary:

> **kick out (at someone or something)**
>   to thrust one's foot outward at something. *The ostrich kicked out at the men trying to catch her. The mule kicked out and just missed me.*
>
> – [Source](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kick+out)
>
> **kick**
>   *v.tr.*
>   1. To strike with the foot: *kicked the wall in frustration.*
>
> – [Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kick)

Answer (score -1):

"Kicked the dog" is a meaningful phrase. It needs a subject, like "Sally kicked the dog." But then the meaning is clear: Sally kicked something. What did she kick? The dog.

"Kicked out at the dog" has no clear meaning.

Perhaps you have heard a sentence like, "Sally kicked out the dog". That is, without the "at". To "kick someone or something out" is to force it to leave the premises. If you kick out the dog, you are forcing him to leave your house or the room or whatever space is under discussion. It is common to say that a landlord kicked out a tenant, or that a man was kicked out of the house by his wife. Note that when "kicked" is used this way it is not being used literally. When a woman kicks her husband out of the house, she does not literally kick him. (Well, she might, but that's not what the word means.)

Comment: That sentence is written in Enid Blyton's novel named The Burned Cottage. I have copied from there.

Comment: Kicking out at definitely has a meaning. It's similar to the "at" in "lashing out at".

Comment: Well, I don't recall ever hearing "kicking out at", either as a synonym for "lashing out at" or any other way. Perhaps its a regionalism. I guess like any case of "I have never heard this word or phrase", it could be that I just happen to not have seen or noticed it.

Comment: Are you from the US? It's possible it's British English - that's what I speak and what the source text OP got it from was written in. Also, I didn't mean to imply it was a synonym for lashing out at, just that it's a similar usage of "at", meaning "in the general direction of".

Comment: No, it isn't just BrE.  It's common over here as well.  Ngram viewer has statistically equivalent usage in both BrE and AmE.  However, "kick out the" is a great deal more common than "kick out at the", and "lash out at" is also a great deal more common than "kick out at".  Probably because in both cases they are done a great deal more often.  Kicking out at something isn't nice, after all.

Comment: I just did a Bing search for "kick out at". thefreedictionary.com defines it as an idiom meaning "to thrust one's foot outward at something", and they give the example "The ostrich kicked out at the men trying to catch her." I see a bunch of references to "Kick out at 2", which apparently is something to do with professional wrestling. I didn't see any explanation of what it means or context to give a clue, just a title. Besides that, all the examples I see are really the "kick out' idiom specifying a place or time, like "synonyms for 'kick out' at thesaurus.com" and "kick out at 17" ...

Comment: ... referring to parents kicking a kid out of the house at 17. Oh, there is the idiom, "get a kick out of", meaning to get a thrill from something, like, "I really get a kick out of roller coasters". So from thefreedictionary.com reference, which lists it as an American idiom, I'll concede it must be used somewhere in the U.S. But as I say, I don't recall ever hearing it.